# Loading several samples from a file simulink

Tags: buffer, loading, simulink

I have a problem loading samples using the "from file" block in Simulink. I have a matrix with 68 channels and 500 samples for each channel, and before this sample goes into the processing blocks,I want to make load all of them so the matrix ends up having the dimensions 68 x 500 .

Since simulink loads the samples incrementally, is there a way i can store the samples until all of them have been loaded? I have tried with a buffer but its not working for me. Thanks in advance!

Ernest

Comment: If you want all the data (as a matrix) then why not just load the variable into the MATLAB Workspace and use a `Constant` block?

Comment: It worked thanks so much!